# Retagging questions that have been closed and migrated

Tags: support, tags

[This question has been closed and migrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919084/ms-excel-bubble-trouble-creating-amazing-looking-charts-closed) with the tag `ms-excel`, the tag for excel is just that. This question has led to several new questions being tagged `ms-excel` and possibly overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

After some searching I found the [question Remou (the original poster of this question) was referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919084/ms-excel-bubble-trouble-creating-amazing-looking-charts-closed).

A moderator should be able to clean that tag out; though I don't know if we should change it since [Microsoft Access is referred to as `ms-access`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access). Keeping the `ms-excel` tag would seem consistent.

If anything, we should re-tag `excel` to `ms-excel` to retain consistency.

Comment: While ms-excel seems consistent, excel is what was chosen by the vast majority of posters asking about Excel at an early stage, access was originally chosen by access posters, but the tag was changed to ms-access by editors due to ambiguity.

Comment: I'd vote for 'Excel' also.